# Timeline looks broken for post with long title

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

I am looking at [the timeline for the Chuck Norris question](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/4009/timeline). Here's what I see:

[image]

It appears that the design can't accommodate questions with such long titles. When the title wraps to the next line, it pushes the actual content to the right and out of view (looks like a `float` issue).

Now, this is not a show-stopper, as there *is* a horizontal scrollbar at the very bottom of the page, so I *can* bring the actual content into view. However, I think it would be less confusing and more convenient if the question title were allotted more vertical space or had an `overflow:hidden`.

Comment: Chuck Norris can lead a horse to water and make it `float`, and make the `overflow` `hidden`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FireFox only CSS bug.  A fun one too.

I've tweaked the styles to just hide the overflow, which fixes the problem on FireFox (and does nothing in the typical "sane length title" case).

This change will go out with our nightly deploy.

Comment: Well now, part of the title disappears.

Comment: Thanks, Kevin. @Eldros: I can totally live with that. I hope so can others. (This is an edge case anyway, most question titles are considerably shorter.)

Comment: @Reg: I'm just saying. :)